# I want to get the item values be like 'Process the Refund for policy number:' from dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to  get the item values be like 'Process the Refund for policy number:' after policy number i have numbers those are dynamic numbers  similar values to get from the
DynamoDB it is not primary key, sort key and global indexes those attributes need to  get from the the DynamoDB

i am trying these

```py
resp= table.query(FilterExpression=Attr('subject').eq('Process the Refund for policy number:')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Scan` not `Query`:

```
table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('subject').contains('Process the Refund for policy number:'))
```

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion.
its is working but the data is not updating in the google spreadsheet from DynamoDB to  spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Leeroy Hannigan, I want to automate the data from DynamoDB to google spreadsheet with subject attribute having static value is  Process the Refund for policy number: and after : we have dynamic values those digits may vary so those kind of values I need to get and update in the sheet
example : Process the Refund for policy number: XXXXXXXX!, these xxxxxxxx is dynamic

Comment: That's an entirely different question. I suggest you add a new question with the relevant details.